# Why does parse_graph6 seem to be missing from networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

The networkx [docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.0/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.graph6.parse_graph6.html) say there is a function for parsing graph6 strings called `parse_graph6` (`networkx.readwrite.graph6.parse_graph6`), but it doesn't seem to exist. Did this function go away, or am I doing something wrong?

```
jack@hitch:~$ pip show networkx | grep Version
Version: 2.1
jack@hitch:~$ python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import networkx
>>> dir(networkx.readwrite.graph6)
['NetworkXError', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '_generate_graph6_bytes', 'data_to_n', 'from_graph6_bytes', 'islice', 'n_to_data', 'not_implemented_for', 'nx', 'open_file', 'read_graph6', 'sys', 'to_graph6_bytes', 'write_graph6', 'write_graph6_file']

>>> networkx.readwrite.graph6.parse_graph6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse_graph6'
>>>
```

Comment: Does "mentioning" `networkx.readwrite.graph6.parse_graph6` raise any errors? According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=dir#dir), "the resulting list [returned by `dir`] is not necessarily complete".

Comment: Yes, mentioning it gives an AttributeError.  (updated—see above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse_graph6` is renamed to `from_graph6_bytes` as seen in this [diff](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/commit/5c22e401bdf5fdff19147bd1328a934f8d3205b5?diff=unified#diff-702b35c7ef6d54af79be44bd6f64b9e7R74).

Going forward in versions of networkx greater than **2.0**, `from_graph6_bytes` is used.